# ncurses + SLD2 and SDL2_Mixer: No sound when trying to play mp3

Tags: c++, audio, sdl, mp3

I am writing a program in C++ that uses the ncurses library and also plays sound effects. While the build compiles, there is no sound.

I have installed and added both the SDL2 and SDL2_Mixer frameworks to my IDE project (I'm using Xcode). I have also added the mp3 file to the same directory as my other project files. Here's my code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2_Mixer/SDL_Mixer.h>
#if defined(WIN32)
#include "curses.h"
#else
#include <curses.h>
#endif
...
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
Mix_Music *music;

// Initialize music.
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to initialize SDL\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (Mix_Init(MIX_INIT_MP3) != MIX_INIT_MP3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to initialize SDL_mixer\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (Mix_OpenAudio(MIX_DEFAULT_FREQUENCY, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 1024) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to initialize audio\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
Mix_AllocateChannels(1); // only need background music
music = Mix_LoadMUS("sound.mp3");
if (music) {
    Mix_PlayMusic(music, -1);
}
...
Mix_HaltMusic();
Mix_FreeMusic(music);
Mix_CloseAudio();
Mix_Quit();


return 0;
}
```

The build compiles successfully, I go to the terminal and open my project, and then... no sound!? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update: it seems that my "sound.mp3" file is not loading properly. Perhaps I'm not referencing it correctly in my main()? It is in the same directory as the other files in the project.

Comment: What `SDL_GetError` tells you? It doesn't matter if file is in the 'same' directory, process have its 'current working directory', and relative paths resolved against it. If you haven't changed working directory, it is passed by parent process. You can check it with [getcwd](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) if you're not sure.

Comment: Thank you, keltar. SDL_GetError tells me: "Couldn't open 'sound.mp3'." After I do a getcwd inquiry, it tells me that my working directory is: /private/tmp. (Since I'm running ncurses, I had to allocate a temp directory for the project's build, and that directory is: /tmp.) Any idea what the problem is? Perhaps it's just not recognizing the file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that what was needed was an absolute path to the music file:

```
Mix_AllocateChannels(1); 
music = Mix_LoadMUS("/.../sound.mp3");
if (music) {
Mix_PlayMusic(music, -1);
}
```